# Listview column widths set at design time not used at run time

Tags: c#, listview

I've defined column widths manually by dragging column borders in a listview control at design time but at run time all the columns appear with the same width.

Code in InitialiseComponent is

```
// 
        // lstLicenses
        // 
        this.lstLicenses.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.Company,
        this.ExpiryDate,
        this.MaxUsers,
        this.Key});
        this.lstLicenses.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(465, 46);
        this.lstLicenses.MultiSelect = false;
        this.lstLicenses.Name = "lstLicenses";
        this.lstLicenses.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(565, 228);
        this.lstLicenses.TabIndex = 18;
        this.lstLicenses.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.lstLicenses.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;`
```

`
It seems as though the design time column width information isn't getting stored. Workaround is to define column widths manually after load as shown below but this shouldn't be necessary.

```
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Licenses";
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, sEnv);

                DataSet Licenses = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(Licenses, "Licenses");
                int iLicensesRows = Licenses.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                foreach (DataRow row in Licenses.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                ListViewItem LVI = lstLicenses.Items.Add(row["Company"].ToString());
                LVI.SubItems.Add(row["ExpiryDate"].ToString());
                LVI.SubItems.Add(row["MaxUsers"].ToString());
                LVI.SubItems.Add(row["Key"].ToString());
                }
                lstLicenses.Columns[0].Width = 100;
                lstLicenses.Columns[1].Width = 130;
                lstLicenses.Columns[2].Width = 85;
                lstLicenses.Columns[3].Width = 225;
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the design time column widths to be used at run time?

Answer (score -1):

**Problem :** you are setting the `widths` of your `ListView` `columns` onceagain manually by following Statements:

```
                lstLicenses.Columns[0].Width = 100;
                lstLicenses.Columns[1].Width = 130;
                lstLicenses.Columns[2].Width = 85;
                lstLicenses.Columns[3].Width = 225;
```

the above statements override your designtime `Widths`.so finally your `ListView` Column widths are set based on above statements.

**Solution** you should comment/remove the above statements to get the `Widths` which are set at `designtime`.

**Comlete Solution:**

```
            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Licenses";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, sEnv);

            DataSet Licenses = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(Licenses, "Licenses");
            int iLicensesRows = Licenses.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            foreach (DataRow row in Licenses.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
            ListViewItem LVI = lstLicenses.Items.Add(row["Company"].ToString());
            LVI.SubItems.Add(row["ExpiryDate"].ToString());
            LVI.SubItems.Add(row["MaxUsers"].ToString());
            LVI.SubItems.Add(row["Key"].ToString());
            }

           //Comment or remove the below statements to get design time widths.

           /*lstLicenses.Columns[0].Width = 100;
            lstLicenses.Columns[1].Width = 130;
            lstLicenses.Columns[2].Width = 85;
            lstLicenses.Columns[3].Width = 225; */
```

Comment: looks like you did not even try it, I've tried it and the OP's problem is obviously present. Only the first column retains *design-time Width*, all other columns don't. BTW, the code he posted (that you said it overrides the design Width) is what he tried to keep the Widths as what he wants, but of course that's not at design-time.